# Google-Analytics API to track Site Search?

Tags: search, google-analytics

So there's this nifty _trackPageview() api method on a tracker object, but is there a corresponding method that can be used to manually track a search? In other words, `_trackPageview()` reports to GA that a user hit a page. I want something like `_trackSearch("terms")` that would report to GA that a user searched for something.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "search result" and where?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect more specifically what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not exactly what I was looking for, it seems that one can generate virtual page views to track search results programatically.

Suppose that you've set up a Site Search parameter called "q", so that when a URI is tracked that contains `q=these+are+some+terms`, GA will mark it as a search hit. One can use the `_trackPageview()` method to generate virtual search hits like so:

```
pageTracker._trackPageview('/custom/search?q=These+are+some+terms')
```

Comment: Sounds to me like this is going to create 2x impressions for the page.

Comment: Google now has public documentation mirroring your approach. Perhaps GA is smart enough to count this impression as a "sub-impression" (for lack of a better word). http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012264

Comment: It does sound like it will inflate "pageviews". One work-around here, but this does not look elegant or integrated. https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/asynchronous-tracking-code-snippet/mX9gict4FmA

Answer (score 1):

I pass search parameters by GET, so the URL for a search on "TEST" is

```
http://www.example.com/search?q=TEST
```

Selecting `Content` -> `Site Search` from my analytics account gives me a list of all keywords searched.

To learn more, [check the documentation](https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=91491&hl=en_US), especially the [How do I set up Site Search for my profile?](https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=75817) page.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using GET. I managed to use the onsubmit attribute of the form to fire the javascript I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Maybe you could make your question more specific then!